# Why is there no 'BountyClose' vote cast for so many bounty questions in SEDE?

Tags: support, data-explorer

I wrote [Activity During a Bounty Period](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/340411/activity-during-a-bounty-period?Year=2015) to try and get the date range for when a bounty is active on Stack Overflow. My aim is to see what other activity there was on the post while the bounty was active.

You can see that the last few columns are coming from the Votes table.  Note that the "BountyCloseDate" column is only populated for about one-third of the bounties posted in 2015.  I'd expect that to be the case for bounties that haven't ended yet, but that should only be true for bounties that were started within the past week.

I looked at the revision history of a few examples and found that they do have a close date listed.

- [Read binary file into a struct](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2384/revisions)
- [What is a selector engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/26393/revisions)
- [How are virtual functions and vtable implemented?](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/99297/revisions)

These bounties all ended back in April, so I'm wondering why the BountyEnd vote isn't showing up in the data explorer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a bounty is awarded, the vote is cast on the *answer* that receives the bounty, but you're always joining to question posts by virtue of having the join to the bounty start vote.

This will, in effect, only return bounty completion information for bounties where no answer was chosen (either by the assigning user, or automatically).

I think [modifying the query slightly](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/340441/activity-during-a-bounty-period?Year=2015)* will give you results closer to what you were expecting, although there's still a few blanks in there I can't immediately explain.

<sub>*Warning: Just-woke-up SQL, check for accuracy</sub>

Comment: Well, that's going to complicate things. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I tweaked the query a bit, I think that'll mostly resolve the problem…err although I imagine the results will get cartesian-product-y for any question with multiple bounties

Comment: Thank you for the updated query. I might pull this apart into two queries, one where an answer was chosen and one where it wasn't, since that's relevant to what I'm trying to find out (bounty effectiveness).